# Need to Extend Volume

Tags: windows-server-2008, partitioning

Ok Here is where I am... I have an HP Proliant with 8 Drives configured as RAID5, and C:\Drive Disk 0 and D:\ drive Disk 1. I need to add more space to Disk 0 (C:) and have 150GB available on Disk 1 (D:).

I tested the Disk Mgmt on D:\ and freed up 4GB which now shows to be Unallocated. How do I add the 4GB of Unallocated to the c:\?

When I click on C:\ the Menu shows "Extend Volume" as Grayed Out not Black but the D:\ Drive shows Extend Volume as selectable/black.

Comment: What size disks, what server model/version, etc., etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Extending a disk partition normally requires the free space to be adjacent to the partition that you are trying to extend. I suspect that the 4GB you freed is at the end of the D:\ partition. [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) has a tool that can move a partition over so they are adjacent.  You also can boot from a [live CD](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php) capable of doing this.

Beware that any repartitioning operation involving relocation of existing data on the disk may take numerous hours to complete. Depending on which partition editing tool you are using, you may or may not have access to useful information about time remaining or percentage completion. Terminating such a process in mid-stream, either deliberately or by accident, may be unrecoverable. It is essential to have full and complete backups before attempting something of this nature.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Paragon Partition Manager Server](http://www.paragon-software.com/business/pm-server/), I have used it on several Win2008 boxes and one SBS2008, works very fine on RAIDs too, I never had any problems. But, as Kafuka already said, if you want to relocate existing data, plan enough time for the operation and don´t get panicky if the progress bar seems to be stuck, even for hours.